# Voila extension on JupyterLab not rendering

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-lab, voila

I am having issue rendering Voila in the JupyterLab, It keeps running without showing the dashboard, I have also tried installing the @jupyter-voila/jupyterlab-preview from the Extension Manager in JupyterLab
and I get the following message:

[image]

Here the list of all extension on my pc:

[image]

Comment: You should not install `@voila-dashboards/jupyterlab-preview` from extension manager if it is correctly installed via pip/conda (which it is). Have you tried upgrading viola? Like `pip install -U voila` or `conda update -c conda-forge voila` (depending on how you installed it). The current version is 2.0.10 but you seem to have 2.0.2

Comment: If the problem exists after upgrade, are there any errors shown in the [browser developer console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools#how_to_open_the_devtools_in_your_browser)?

Comment: @krassowski the issue still persisting I have tried updating both voila and the extension